# Can I use cargo install to distribute a binary built by build.rs?

Tags: build, rust, rust-cargo

#### Background

I have a crate that provides a CLI tool with subcommands, much [like cargo itself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/external-tools.html#custom-subcommands). For example, running

```sh
tool subcommand arg1 arg2 arg3
```

would look for an executable called `tool-subcommand` on the user's `PATH` and run it like this:

```sh
tool-subcommand subcommand arg1 arg2 arg3
```

`tool` is implemented in `src/main.rs`, and I have some subcommands defined:

- `tool-foo` lives in `src/bin/foo.rs`
- `tool-bar` lives in `src/bin/bar.rs`

Each has a `[[bin]]` entry in my `Cargo.toml`.

When I run `cargo install`, all of them are installed in `~/.cargo/bin` as expected.

---

#### Question

There's an executable written in C that lives in another repo. I can build it using `build.rs`, producing a binary called `tool-baz`. I'd like `cargo install` to build/install that for my users too.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to point Cargo at binaries created by `build.rs`. I *could* make a custom static library build target for the C executable, wrap it in a Rust shim and distribute that, but that's both messy and a pain.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some external tool like [cargo-make](https://github.com/sagiegurari/cargo-make) might be a solution for you (it's like a makefile but in toml and also cargo-aware).

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I don't think cargo-make will fix my problem. The issue is that I expect users of my crate to be able to get all of its binaries by running `cargo install`; I'm already able to build the binaries, it's just a question of getting cargo to install them for me. From what I can tell, the best I can do with `cargo-make` and `build.rs` is manually copying files around myself, which seems error prone. (It also means that `cargo uninstall` won't work.)

Comment: The problem here, that build.rs is executed *before* the build, not after. So it can't do anything after the binaries are made. I believe you can come up with some hacks like sym-links (but please don't, it does serve the different purpose).

Comment: Thanks, @Kitsu. It looks like this RFC is exactly what I'd need, but unfortunately it hasn't seen movement in almost 2 years: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2376